# (#12) singular published story API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to share photos on Instagram using Graph API. Does anyone know how to fix the error I'm getting? It gives an error even though I share it as in the document, I gave all permissions for the user.

Using Request 1

[https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/ig-userid/media?image_url=https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/53/45/31/500_F_53453175_hVgYVz0WmvOXPd9CNzaUcwcibiGao3CL.jpg&caption=%test&access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/ig-userid/media?image_url=https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/53/45/31/500_F_53453175_hVgYVz0WmvOXPd9CNzaUcwcibiGao3CL.jpg&caption=%test&access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

Using Request 2

https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/ig-userid/media?image_url=https://as2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/53/45/31/500_F_53453175_hVgYVz0WmvOXPd9CNzaUcwcibiGao3CL.jpg&caption=%test

Facebook Example Request

```
graph.facebook.com/17841400008460056/media
  ?image_url=https//www.example.com/images/bronzed-fonzes.jpg
  &caption=#BronzedFonzes!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this permission to generate an access token:

- ads_management
- business_management
- instagram_basic
- instagram_content_publish
- pages_read_engagement

It works for me.

https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/id/media?image_url=https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535713875002-d1d0cf377fde?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8 & caption=your own caption & access_token={your access token}